# How can I properly show this code snippet in HTML?

Tags: html, html-encode

This is a very basic HTML snippet I have:

```
<pre>
    <code class="language-java">
        import java.util.List;

        public class Foo {
            public void foo(List<List<Integer>> bar) {
            }
        }
    </code>
</pre>
```

Where I expect to see the following when opening in a browser:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public void foo(List<List<Integer>> bar) {
    }
}
```

However something breaks in the parameter list of the method and what gets rendered is:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public void foo(List> bar) {
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Isn't it enough to be in `code` tag to hint the browser not to interpret anything inside as HTML? Or is this a different problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put angle brackets (even in a `<code>` tag) they're still interpreted as HTML elements. You can get around this by escaping the `<` symbol using `&lt;`. Working example below:

```html
<pre>
<code class="language-java">
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public void foo(List&lt;List&lt;Integer>> bar) {
    }
}
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: If my answer solved your issue please consider clicking the grey checkmark to accept it, thanks.

Comment: @kfedorov91: Before suggesting to someone to accept your answer, check their question history first to see if they've accepted answers to their previous questions before. If they have, there's a pretty good chance they'll accept your answer if it did help them. Otherwise your comment may not come off the way you intended. In this case, it does seem like the asker knows the feature better than you do, given that they've accepted answers to *hundreds* of questions...